# how to get the count of category in three tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
category  table 

-----------------------
catid  | catname
-------------------------

Deal table
------------------------
dealid |  name | catid |
-----------------------


Cement Table
-----------------------
cid |  cname  | catid
-----------------------

ordertable
---------------------
oid | oname | catid
---------------------
```

above three tables using i want to get the total count of catid and using order by desc clause.how to write the sql query?

```
the result like this way

catid  catcount catname
-----------------------
1       20        xxx
2       19        YYY
```

Comment: please show the result sample you want to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union` to create a subquery containing all types of categories:

```
select  c.name
,       count(*) as TotalCount
from    (
        select  catid
        from    deal
        union all
        select  catid
        from    comment
        union all
        select  catid
        from    ordertable
        ) as lst
join    category c
on      c.catid = lst.catid
group by
        c.name
order by
        count(*) desc
```